# Getting the value of a property using it's string name in pure Swift using reflection

Tags: swift, reflection

I want to use Swift (not Objective-C runtime) Reflection to create a method like this:

```
func valueFor(property:String, of object:Any) -> Any? {
    ...
}
```

To some extent, I can do this using:

```
func valueFor(property:String, of object:Any) -> Any? {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: object)
    return mirror.descendant(property)
}
```

With

```
class TestMe {
    var x:Int!
}

let t = TestMe()
t.x = 100
let result = valueFor(property: "x", of: t)
print("\(result); \(result!)")
```

This prints out what I'd expect:

> Optional(100); 100

When I do:

```
let t2 = TestMe()    
let result2 = valueFor(property: "x", of: t2)
print("\(result2)")
```

The output is:

> Optional(nil)

This might seem reasonable, except that if I do:

```
var x:Int!
print("\(x)")
```

This prints out:

> nil

and not `Optional(nil)`. The bottom line is that I'm having difficulty programmatically determining that the value of `t2.x` is `nil` using my `valueFor` method.

If I continue the above code with:

```
if result2 == Optional(nil)! {
    print("Was nil1")
}

if result2 == nil {
    print("Was nil2")
}
```

Neither of these `print` statements output anything.

When I put a breakpoint into Xcode and look at the value of `result2` with the debugger, it shows:

```
▿ Optional<Any>
  - some : nil
```

So, my question is: **How can I determine if the original member variable was nil using the result from `valueFor`?**

**Additional1:**
If I do:

```
switch result2 {
case .some(let x):
    // HERE
    break
default:
    break
}
```

and put a breakpoint at `HERE`, the value of x turns out to be `nil`. But, even if I assign it to an `Any?`, comparing it to `nil` is not true.

**Additional2:**
If I do:

```
switch result2 {
case .some(let x):
    let z:Any? = x
    print("\(z)")
    if z == nil {
        print("Was nil3")
    }
    break
default:
    break
}
```

This prints out (only):

> Optional(nil)

I find this especially odd. `result2` prints out exactly the same thing!

Comment: Are you using Swift 3.1?

Comment: I believe so. I'm using Xcode 8.3.

Comment: You might want to test on [this Linux based sandbox](https://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl) just to be sure you aren't hitting some weird compiler/runtime error on Xcode. Probably won't make a difference given Swift shared codebase across platforms...

Comment: @PauloMattos The [swift3] tag is only for questions *directly* related to changes in the language for that version – I don't believe this question is.

Comment: @PauloMattos -- I just tried this with Ubuntu Swift 3.1, good idea. Same result.

Comment: @Hamish Ok, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit of a hack, but I think it's going to solve the problem for me. I'm still looking for better solutions:

```
func isNilDescendant(_ any: Any?) -> Bool {
    return String(describing: any) == "Optional(nil)"
}

func valueFor(property:String, of object:Any) -> Any? {
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: object)
    if let child = mirror.descendant(property), !isNilDescendant(child) {
        return child
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is deeper than I thought. I'm having difficulties in general **comparing** the result of the original `valueFor` function, or non-nil values of the second `valueFor` function.

Comment: No, ignore that last comment. I was mistaken. I had thought I couldn't cast these values when they are non-nil, but I can.

Comment: After a while, it hit me that `mirror.descendant("x")` should actually return `Optional(nil)` for property `x: Int!`. It means that **x** exists on this object (the outer optional) but its current value is nil (the inner optional). Sorry iff this was obvious to you all along, haha... but I can't yet explain your remaining issues :(

Comment: It seems that these results have changed with recent Swift versions-- e.g., Swift 4.1.2 seems to produce the expected results for `valueFor(property:String, of object:Any)` defined above.

Comment: No. Again, ignore that last comment! :). If anything, the problem of determining if a member value is nil now seems harder. Here's an example nil value `Optional(Swift.ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<Swift.String>.none)`

Answer (score 0):

well, i know it has been 4 years, but I am on Xcode 12 and still facing the same issue.  since this question seems to be unanswered, I will add what worked for me.

```
func valueFor(property: String, of object: Any) -> Any? {
    let optionalPropertyName = "some"
    let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: object)
    if let child = mirror.descendant(property) {
        if let optionalMirror = Mirror(reflecting: child), optionalMirror.displayStyle == DisplayStyle.optional {
            return optionalMirror.descendant(optionalPropertyName)
        } else {
            return child
        }
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

by using Mirror to check for optional and then extract the optional using "some" you get back either a true object or nil.  when this is returned to the caller via the Any? return, you are now able to nil check the value and have that work appropriately.